# SlideDown() using JavaScript not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Thanks to @mplungjan for helping me complete my first query which can be found here: [Remove div with button click using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651229/remove-div-with-button-click-using-javascript)

The code works as intended however when we tried to get the slideDown() function to work it looks a bit... laggy and then just pops up without the animation being completed as intended.

Would like some support to see how can this be fixed.

Find below working code:

```js
$(function() {
  var $original = $('#ValuWrapper'),
    $crossButton = $('#cross'),
    $content = $("#content");

  $content.on("click", ".cross", function() {
    if ($(this).is("#cross")) return false;
    var $cross = $(this);
    $(this).next().slideUp(400, function() {
      $(this).remove();
      $cross.remove();
    });
  });

  $("#repeat").on("click", function() {
    $content.append($crossButton.clone(true).removeAttr("id"));
    $content.append(
      $original.clone(true)
      .hide() // if sliding
      .attr("id",$original.attr("id")+$content.find("button.cross").length)
      .slideDown("slow") // does not slide much so remove if you do not like it
    );
  });

});
```

```css
#content { height:100%}

#cross { display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <button type="button" class="buttonImgTop cross" id="cross">X</button>
  <div id="ValuWrapper"> 
    ...content comes here... <br/>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="buttonImg" id="repeat">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly use below updated code for animation.

```
$("#repeat").on("click", function() {
$content.append($crossButton.clone(true).removeAttr("id"));
$content.append(
  $original.clone(true)
   // if sliding
  .attr("id",$original.attr("id")+$content.find("button.cross").length).hide());
   // does not slide much so remove if you do not like it
   $("#"+$original.attr("id")+$content.find("button.cross").length).slideDown("slow");//change
```

});

```
and remove #content { height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you clone the `$original` you should reset its height so jQuery knows what height its got to animate to.

E.G: `$original.css('height', $(this).height())`

**See demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  var $original = $('#ValuWrapper'),
    $crossButton = $('#cross'),
    $content = $("#content");

  $content.on("click", ".cross", function() {
    if ($(this).is("#cross")) return false;
    var $cross = $(this);
    $(this).next().slideUp(400, function() {
      $(this).remove();
      $cross.remove();
    });
  });

  $("#repeat").on("click", function() {
    $content.append($crossButton.clone(true).removeAttr("id"));
    $content.append(
      $original.clone(true)
      .css('height', $(this).height())//set height
      .hide() .attr("id",$original.attr("id")+$content.find("button.cross").length)
      .slideDown("slow")
    );
  });

});
```

```css
#content { height:100%;}
#cross { display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <button type="button" class="buttonImgTop cross" id="cross">X</button>
  <div id="ValuWrapper"> 
    ...content comes here...
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="buttonImg" id="repeat">Add</button>
```